# how to load a string with long text as dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a string in python and want to convert it to dictionary, the problem is that the string has a text with multi line and several double quotes. 
How can I do this effectively,
Here is a sample text string

```
string = '{'reviewTime': '03 4, 2013', 'reviewText': 'Not only do these panties not even come up and cover my belly button, they are like a tight stretchy girdle.  I will go back to myVanity Fair Women\'s Perfectly Yours Lace Nouveau Brief #13001of which I have several pair in black and white and as I have stated previously they feel too big which I like, bloomery, if you will.  I would not recommend tailored seamless brief panties because of the girdle effect and I would have to buy three or four sizes larger than my size 8.  I\'m glad I only ordered one pair to try.  Out in the garbage.  Very disappointed that Vanity Fair would make something so "cheap."Update 3-5-13:  I gave these to my best friend who wears a size 5 or 6 panty.  She is delighted with my "high price" taste.', 'helpful': {'nHelpful': 3, 'outOf': 3}, 'reviewerID': 'U715225167', 'reviewHash': 'R792001309', 'categories': [['Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry', 'Women', 'Clothing', 'Lingerie, Sleep & Lounge', 'Intimates', 'Panties', 'Briefs'], ['Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry', 'Women', 'Plus-Size']], 'unixReviewTime': 1362355200, 'itemID': 'I435919831', 'rating': 1.0, 'summary': 'Fits like a girdle!', 'categoryID': 0}'
```

revieText field is the one have having trouble with

Comment: how are you reading it in?

Comment: The 'string' you provided is already a diet. What's the problem, exactly?

Comment: sorry, the string is enclosed with single quote 'string'